# Poisson process and Heaviside function

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, poisson-process

Show that Poisson process $p(t)$ of intensity $\lambda$ can be written as 
$$p(t)=\sum_{t>t_n}\delta(t-t_n),$$ where function $\delta:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is Heaviside's function:
$$\delta(t)=\begin{cases}0  \textrm{ if }t<0\\1 \textrm{ if }t\geq0,
\end{cases}$$
and sequence $(t_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is sequence of random variables of vaules in $\mathbb{R_+}$ such that increments
$$\Delta t_i=t_i-t_{i-1},$$ where $i=1,2\ldots, t_0=0$ are nonnegative, independent  and have the same distribution of density
$$g(t)=\lambda e^{-\lambda t}$$ for $t\geq0.$

Comment: I have tried to calculate this from definition of Poisson process, but it doesn't work. Can you help me ?  Give any tip ?

Comment: What definiton of Poisson process do you use ?

Comment: Definition with supremum.

Comment: @Snape Do you mean  $$p(t) = \sup\left\{n\geqslant 0 : \sum_{k=0}^n X_k\leqslant t\right\}  $$ where $X_0\equiv0$ and $X_n\stackrel{i.i.d.}\sim\mathsf{Exp}(\lambda)$ for $n\geqslant1$?

Comment: Yes, exactly this definition.